Reference request: hyperfinite cross product
Given a countable essentially free ergodic non-singular group action $G \curvearrowright (X, \mu)$ on a standard measure space, suppose $\mu$ is a non-atomic probability measure and $\alpha: G \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is the group homomorphism that defines the $G$-action. Under our assumption, the von Neumann algebra $L^{\infty}(X, \mu) \overline{\rtimes}_{\alpha} G$ is a factor. One can refer to this post for more details. Does anyone know references that discuss necessary conditions for the factor $L^{\infty}(X, \mu) \overline{\rtimes}_{\alpha} G$ to be hyperfinite?

Assuming you meant $G$ to be a countable discrete group, the measure is a probability measure (or a finite measure in general - it doesn’t make any difference), and the action is measure-preserving, then it is a quite standard exercise to show the factor is hyperfinite iff $G$ is amenable.

(And the easy direction is to show amenability of $G$ follows from hyperfiniteness of the factor. That is a direct consequence of the fact that a von Neumann subalgebra of a hyperfinite tracial von Neumann algebra is always hyperfinite. So if you just want necessary conditions, that’s already enough.)

Thanks for your inputs. It would be fine if $G$ is assumed to be a countable discrete group and $\mu$ is a probability measure. However, I prefer not to only consider measure-preserving group action. If necessary, you could only consider the non-singular action (namely $g\mu\sim\mu$ for all $g\in G$), and references related to this case are also welcomed.

It might be better to specifically say that in the post in that case, as otherwise people might assume the action is pmp, since that is the most well-studied case. Also, assuming the action is non-singular is necessary, as otherwise you don’t even have an action on $L^\infty(X, \mu)$. I don’t know of any answer to the question though, given that I’m only familiar with the pmp case. $G$ being amenable is still sufficient, that I know, but probably not necessary, I would guess.

Got it. Will edit the post now.

The hyperfiniteness you are asking about is equivalent to amenability of the action; it goes back to Zimmer and essentially was the motivation for his definition of amenable actions. As for the latter, there is a lot of equivalent defintions (the original definition of Zimmer not being the simplest one to work with). In a sense, the most constructive one is due to Renault (actually, in a more general groupoid context) and stems from Day's approximate characterization of amenable groups: a non-singular action $G \curvearrowright (X, \mu)$ is amenable if there is a sequence of maps $x\mapsto \lambda_n^x$ from $X$ to the space of probability measures on $G$ which is asymptotically equivariant in the sense that $\|\lambda_n^{gx}-g\lambda_n^x\|\to 0$ for any $g\in G$ and almost all $x\in X$.
Of course, any action of an amenable group is amenable. However (which was another motivation of Zimmer), there are numerous examples of amenable actions of non-amenable groups. The action space in these situations can usually be considered as a boundary of the group, be it in the topological category (for instance, the boundary action of a hyperbolic group) or in the measure category (for instance, the action on the Poisson boundary). The simplest example is the action of a finitely generated free group on its boundary (the space of infinite irreducible words $\equiv$ the space of ends $\equiv$ the Gromov boundary) endowed with any quasi-invariant measure.

Thank you for your references. I came across the same definition of amenable group action in Ozawa's textbook (something called $C^$-algebra ... finite dimensional approximation*), and, if I recall, the definition in your answer is the one for a general amenable group action. It is new to me that $L^{\infty}(X, \mu) \overline{\rtimes}_{\alpha} G$ being hyperfinite is equivalent to the amenability of the group action. I currently do not have access to mathscinet but will look into papers written by Zimmer and Renault.
